# magento 2 checkout slow loading after all optimization done

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

The checkout page on our Magento 2 store is loading insanely slow. Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix this?

I provided a screenshot of the chrome waterfall. As you can see, some files are queued taking more time to load
[image]

How can we speed this up? I checked the TTFB by enabling profiling, but that didn't show any significantly slow things. Please check screenshot.

i have done js and css merging and advance bundling done. cdn, cache enabling varnish and redish also configured stil it is slow 
m1 is loading with 200 items load time - 7- 8
m2 is loading with 200 items load times - 30 -35 
any solution sujections pls to match m2 chekcout to m1

Comment: 1. do You have enable cache and production mode (I guess you have, but I had to ask :))? 2. looks like a lot of time last checkout/ payment/ and estimate-shipng-method. Its mean that there is something happens in backed. Is Your magento connecting to external source to check product availability or check product prices or shipping method or whatever? Maybe waiting and procesing request last so long. If no,  then some backend code is not optimized and last much longer it should be.

Comment: @KonradSiamro 1> enabled 2) no external connection how to check which back-end code is taking time i have enabled profile not find any solution

Comment: Probably You read it but I found something may be helpfull: https://onilab.com/blog/magento-checkout-slow-fix-it-in-8-simple-steps/. If there is everything fine (regarding to link), we should back to backend again. You cant do much more  to investigate issue using profiler. Backend guy should check it. Btw what about console logs and project logs? Maybe there are some errors or something ?

Comment: @KonradSiamro i was already done but no luck

Comment: In that case You have to ask developer to fix it. Or hire another one / or ask some agency to fix it. I looks for something more complicated and there is necessary time for investigate and analyse that case.